# When I click on my pin I want the Pin.Adress to change. I have trouble to get the Clickedfunction + change the Pin.Adress to function together

Tags: c#, maps, xamarin.forms

Basically, I want the pins address property to change when I click it and take the correct value from my database (`currentItem`).

This is the code:

```
void clickThis (object s, Eventargs a)
{

foreach (var currentItem in getItems["results"]) {

      myString = currentItem ["info1"].ToString ();

      var pin = new Pin ();
      pin.Address = "Click for more info";

      pin.Clicked += onButtonClicked1 (pin.PropertyChanging += (sender, e) => {

      pin.Address = myString; //error: onButtonClicked1 only takes 1 argument

      }); 

      theMap.Pins.Add (pin);
    }
 }

void onButtonClicked1 (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Pin pin = (Pin)sender;
    Navigation.PushAsync (new DetailPage (pin.Address));
}
```

---

**Updated**

I managed to fix the error I had with my code, but still, the address of my pin isn't updated after I click it.

```
void clickThis (object s, Eventargs a)
{

foreach (var currentItem in getItems["results"]) {

      myString = currentItem ["info1"].ToString ();

      var pin = new Pin ();
      pin.Address = "Click for more info";

      pin.Clicked += (sender, e) => 
      {
          pin.Address = myString;
          Pin pin = (Pin)sender;
          Navigation.PushAsync (new DetailPage (pin.Address));
      }); 
      theMap.Pins.Add (pin);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you [can see in the docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Pin/), a pin only has simple properties you can set. For doing what you want to, you would need an event handler to subscribe to (such as OnTextUpdated) and thereafter invalidate the map.

Thus, what you request is currently not possible. Maybe you could ask Xamarin to support this at some point in the future?